# Check input for a specific string

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that I am working on that I need some help with. In this script, I want to look at the input variable `%1%` to see if it contains a specific string. If it does, I want to do one thing. If not, I want it to do something else. The input variable is a UNC path and I want to check and see if it contains the string `\\server\share` and I don't want it to be case sensitive. Any ideas?

Comment: as you have not asked a proper question in accordance with the site guidance, I'll just iform you that you are looking at **%1** not **%1%**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input variable is `%1` or `%~1` (with the tilde removing surrounding quotation marks).

There are a couple of ways to check.  You can use variable substring substitution:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set "input=%~1"

if not "%input%"=="%input:specific string=%" (
    rem // input contained the string
) else (
    rem // input did not contain the string
)
```

The way that works is, `%input:specific string=%` replaces all instances of `specific string` with nothing within `%input%`.  So if string before replacement does not equal string after replacement, then the variable contained what you were matching.  [See this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace) for full details on substring substitution.

Or you can use `find` or `findstr`.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

echo(%1 | find /i "some string" && (
    rem // input contained the string
) || (
    rem // input did not contain the string
)
```

The substring substitution method is a little more efficient.

Comment: Thank you. The variable substring substitution worked perfectly. Thanks also for catching my mistype of the input variable.